# ASP.Net using facebook & Google Login to use site functionality without Sign up to native app in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, facebook-login, google-signin

I have searched for many tutorials but it's too confusing thing because everywhere it's different. I have developed site in vb.net & some ecommerce function is there on site. To place any order login is required. I want to add Facebook & Google login in my site that user should be able to use all site functionality without signing up or login to my website using fb or google login. Please suggest a suitable tutorial or documentation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

using code on web.config :

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="google_clientId" value="xxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com" />
    <add key="google_clientEmail" value="xxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com" />
    <add key="google_clientSecret" value="xxxxxxxxxxxx" />
    <add key="google_RedirectUrl" value="http://YOUR-DOMAIN.com/LoginWithGoogle1.aspx" />
    <add key="google_JavaScriptOrigin" value="http://YOUR-DOMAIN.com" />
  </appSettings>
```

in configuration tag
get the website and create account for your loging : [apps.googleusercontent.com](http://apps.googleusercontent.com)

or visit in : [login with google in codeplex open source](https://loginwithgoogle.codeplex.com/)